# Identify link on contextmenu event in safari extension

Tags: javascript, events, dom, contextmenu, safari-extension

I'm trying to build a safari extenstion (mostly for learning purposes) that creates a delicious bookmark, when the user right clicks on a link. I've watched the WWDC Creating a Safari Extension video and everything is working fine.

Except that i don't have a clue how to find out if the user clicked on a link (or just some text) and if so, get it's url and title. What i got so far is this:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", handleContextMenu, false);
function handleContextMenu(event){
    safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event,getSelection().toString());
}
```

But this obviously only gives me a string of the selection. Now, according to the Safari Reference Library `getSelection()` returns a [`DOMSelection` object](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/DOMSelection_idl/Classes/DOMSelection/index.html#//apple_ref/js/cl/DOMSelection). But even there i'm not able to spot a method that gives me a handle on the selected link.

As you might notice, i'm fairly new to this whole javascript and DOM stuff, so please excuse if this is an obvious question :)

Ciao,
 Sven

Comment: A little follow up:

As i'm not able to extract any more context info than the selection i tried to use jQuery to find any link matching the selected text, like this:

`$("a:contains('"+getSelection()+"')");`

But this is very fuzzy, as when clicking on the word 'a' there's a very high probability a link text might contain that word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a simple right-click, the selection will be set *inside* the anchor link. This means you will have its text node selected, but the link node itself won't be. Therefore, it's useless to try to find a link inside a selection.

You can use `DOMSelection`'s `focusNode` to get the last selected text node and check its ancestors until you wind up to an `<a>` element. That should do about what you want.

```
var link = null;
var currentElement = event.getSelection().focusNode;
while (currentElement != null)
{
    if (currentElement.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && currentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
    {
        link = currentElement;
        break;
    }
    currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
}
// link is now an <a> element if the user selected a link's contents
```

Answer (score 0):

zneak's answer did not work for me, so I worked with `event.target` instead of the selection:

```
var link = evt.target;
// get parent node in case of text nodes (old safari versions)
if(link.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    link = link.parentNode;
}
    // if for some reason, it's not an element node, abort
if(link.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    return;
}

// try to get a link element in the parent chain 
while(link != null && 
        currentElement.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && 
        link.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "a") {
    link = link.parentNode;
}
if(link) {
   // do stuff
}
```